# Correct syntax for Doctrine2's query builder substring helper method

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Ok, this problem is probably due to my foggy understanding of the query builder helper methods but for the life of me I cannot find the correct way to use the substring method.

I am attempting to return all results that begin with a specified alphanumeric value. The below code does not throw any errors but it also does not return any results. I have scoured google but apparently there is almost nothing showing how to use substring. I would like to get this working in query builder but I may have to go DQL or raw sql.

```
    $qb->select('p', 't');
    $qb->from('ContentParent', 'p');
    $qb->join('p.titleCurrent', 't');
    $qb->where(
            $qb->expr()->eq($qb->expr()->substring('t.sortTitle', 0, 1), ':letter')
        );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SUBSTRING needs to be one-based.

The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) states:

> For all forms of SUBSTRING(), the position of the first character in
>   the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as
>   1.

With [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm):

```
SELECT SUBSTR('ABCDEFG',3,4) "Substring"
     FROM DUAL;

Substring
---------
CDEF
```

From the [Transact-SQL manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
SELECT LastName, SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, 1) AS Initial
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName like 'Barl%'
ORDER BY LastName
```

You can see from these examples that they, too, are using one-based (Oracle, however, will assume `1` when given `0`).

Simply change your `substring` parameters to `'t.sortTitle', 1, 1` and it will work correctly.