# Limiting the string length of a field in a queried record using doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

This should be really simple to answer and I always check the answer and upvote anyone who pitches in.

I'm having trouble either wording it right or finding the documentation.  I'm using createQueryBuilder and selecting entities / records based on some variables.  What I want to do is target and limit the length of a particular property / field in the query.  The entity is rather large so I'm really wanting to just target the field.  I tried using SUBSTRING(STR, START, END) in the select statement but it doesn't seem to be working.  A quick snippet of the select looks like...

```
->select("p as post, SUBSTRING(p.body, 0, 30) as body")
```

I want to be able to target the post.body but post isn't a class error. :/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619808/1165646) is your answer. `SUBSTRING` starts from 1 when indexing characters. Sadly this isn't mentioned in the Doctrine documentation.
Also Doctrine wouldn't convert `post` to an entity, if scalar data is added to the selection.
You can try to map the `body`(or another) property as `SUBSTRING(body, 1, 30)`, or you could modify the property getter.

```
/** @Entity */
class Post
{
    //...

    /** @Column(name="SUBSTRING(body, 1, 30)") */
    private $bodyExcerpt;

    /** @Column(name="body") */
    private $body;

    public function getBody($excerptOnly = true) {
        if ($excerptOnly) {
            return substr($this->body, 0, 30);
        } else {
            return $this->body;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually kind of helpful.  I updated the code a little bit.  I'm selecting the entity, p as post.  post has a body field that I want to target and limit the length while without having to select make multiple selects.  I'm currently doing the substring and upon getting the results pretty much running a $post->setBody($result['body']) which i don't really want to do.

Comment: That's would be valid but there are times where I need the entirety of the body.  I'll check this for you if this is best and only answer though.  After speaking with some colleagues it seems how I'm doing it is the best answer for my use case.  But I still feel there's an easier way.

Comment: And your on the right track with the annotation but I'm pretty sure that not the correct way.  I'll see if I can't find it. I know I could change the serializer to do what you're attempting.